# Change color in vector Images

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the color of an vector image through a IValueConverter. My vector image has the following format:

```
Viewbox x:Key="ViewBoxName" Stretch="Uniform" x:Shared="False">
    <Canvas Width="256" Height="256" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Canvas  />
        <Canvas >
            <Path Stroke="{DynamicResource GlobalColor}" StrokeThickness="10">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="-------" />
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Figures value are available but i didn't want them here :)

When the parameter has a specified value I want to be able to change the GlobalColor from the viewbox to another for this image only and I want to do that inside the converter.

What I tried to do till now is to parse this viewbox and get to that color, change it and return the viewbox with the new color but on my interface the same color remains as before.

I think i need a new approach for this to work.

Regards.

Comment: Which parameter you are talking about? Can u bind the parameter to your stroke and use the converter to return GlobalColor or the color you want?

Comment: This icon is highlighted when the i click on it, and in this case i want to change the color of the stroke. Can you provide a short example of that are u saying maybe i missed something. Thank you

Comment: So you don't have a property you can bind I guess and my approcach won't help you. Maybe you can use a Trigger?!

Comment: Sadly I have to find a solution to change the stroke color only in converter because of the current architecture of the application

Comment: How are you invoking the converter, it's not in your XAML.

Comment: The converter is invoked from xaml, and gets as content the vector image, and as parameter i would like to give him the click event on the item or something like this